# VBA multi argument function

Tags: vba

I wrote this function to perform item by item array summation, is there a way to make the number of argument dynamic, i.e if the user insert 2 arrays the function will add the  two arrays and if the user insert 3 ones (separated by comma) the function will add the three arrays ...and so on

```
    Option Base 1

Public Function itemByitem(x, y) As Variant
If UBound(x) = UBound(y) Then
ReDim temp(UBound(x)) As Variant
For i = 1 To UBound(x)
temp(i) = y(i) + x(i)
Next i
End If
itemByitem = temp
End Function
```

Comment: Take a look at [ParamArray](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-parameter-arrays).

Comment: Your code assumes `LBound(x)=1` which is not the case for an array defined with the `Array()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the function to add multiple arrays passed as arguments.

#### Example Usage(s)

```
AddArrays Array(1,2,3), Array(4,5,1), Array(2,-1,2)
' ={7, 6, 6}
AddArrays 1, 2, 3
' ={6}
```

#### Function Code

```
Public Function AddArrays(ParamArray args() As Variant) As Variant()
    Dim result() As Variant
    Dim k As Long, k_end As Long, i0 As Long
    Dim i As Long, i_start As Long, n_count As Long
    k_end = UBound(args)
    If k_end = 0 Then
        AddArrays = result
        Exit Function
    End If
    If IsArray(args(0)) Then
        result = args(0)
        i0 = LBound(result)
        For k = 1 To k_end
            i_start = LBound(args(k))
            n_count = UBound(args(k)) - i_start + 1
            For i = 1 To n_count
                result(i - 1 + i0) = result(i - 1 + i0) + args(k)(i - 1 + i_start)
            Next i
        Next k
    Else
        result = Array(args(0))
        i0 = LBound(result)
        For k = 1 To k_end
            result(i0) = result(i0) + args(k)
        Next k
    End If
    AddArrays = result
End Function
```

#### Notes

It won't work with cell ranges, because those are always 2D arrays. But it can accommodate both 0-base and 1-base arrays, just the same. It can even accommodate scalar for arguments, but not mix arrays with scalars.

Comment: thank you for sharing, this is what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it an array of arrays:

```
Dim MultiArray, txt, nrs
txt = Array("txt1", "txt2", "txt3")
nrs = Array("001", "002", "003")
MultiArray = Array(txt, nrs)
```

Than you just add an additional loop in your function to cover the upper level.